# Javascript array.findIndex(x) TypeError: x is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Lemon is not a function online with the following code

```js
var guildList = [];
guildList.push("Lemon");
console.log(guildList); //some debugging code - I can see Lemon here
console.log(guildList.findIndex("Lemon"));
```

returns the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Lemon is not a function
```

I have attempted to check to make sure that the variable is a value (this case "Lemon"), however, this does not mitigate it.

Comment: You should check what that method actually expects to receive: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex, or use the right method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf.

Comment: Apology's, I had read a different API document for javascript, which didn't pass a method. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) accepts a function. You are passing it a string.

Instead, pass a function which checks whether the parameter is equal to `"Lemon"`:

```js
function a() {
  var guildList = [];
  guildList.push("Lemon");
  console.log(guildList);
  return guildList.findIndex(e => e == "Lemon");
}

console.log(a())
```

Or use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead:

```js
function a() {
  var guildList = [];
  guildList.push("Lemon");
  console.log(guildList);
  return guildList.indexOf("Lemon");
}

console.log(a())
```